# Latex, substitution of every word in the glossary

Tags: latex

I have to create some documents with Latex. It is possible to search in these documents every instance of the words that I have defined in a glossary with the word followed by the indication that is present in the glossary, without that I have to search and replace them manually?
i.e. if the word "Hello" is present in the glossary, everywhere in my documents I would like to see "Hello<sub>|g|</sub>"